# Copy Presentation Details to new PlaceHolder programmatically Sitecore 7.2

Tags: sitecore, sitecore7, sitecore7.2

currently I am working on a page that generates a print view of a specific item. So this means I dont need all the stuff from my MainLayout like Navigation etc.

For this reason I have created a new Layout that only has a placeholder.
Lets call this PrintLayout.aspx:

```html
<sc:placeholder ID="PlPrint" runat="server" key="phPrintOutput"></sc:placeholder>
```

In the code behind I have a method that fetches the renderings from the item, but I am stuck at the point where I want to copy them to my phPrintOutput Placeholder on the fly:

```cs
public void AddPresentationDetailsToPlaceHolder(Item item)
{
  List<RenderingReference> renderings = item.Visualization.GetRenderings(Sitecore.Context.Device, false).ToList();
  foreach(RenderingReference r in renderings)
  {
    // How can I apply the renderings on the fly to my phPrintOutput Placeholder??
  }
}
```

Of course it is very important that every sublayout keeps it current datasource.
Any help would be appreciated, thank you all

Comment: Is it an option to use another "device" for your print? This way you don't need to code it - you can just create another layout definition for the device in Sitecore.

Answer (score 0):

You only require to add the control to the placeholder. To do so, please see the code below:

```
public void AddPresentationDetailsToPlaceHolder(Item item)
{
  List<RenderingReference> renderings = item.Visualization.GetRenderings(Sitecore.Context.Device, false).ToList();
  foreach(RenderingReference r in renderings)
  {
      if(r.RenderingID == new ID("Rendering Id you want to be displayed on layout"))
      {
          this.PlPrint.Controls.Add(r.GetControl());
      } 
  }
}
```

This will automatically add the rendering to the layout.